# How to setup 2 Asterisks act as single SIP server

Tags: cluster-computing, asterisk, sip, voip, distributed

We have got SIP solution using two asterisks located at 2 Geo locations US and Europe. Asterisk configurations are being synced so all the configuration is identical except bind address.

We are required to setup both asterisk such SIP Client can be register in any server (US or EU) but work as a single Asterisk/SIP server.

Can anyone advise what is the best way to setup both above asterisk so that both asterisk will be work as single system?

Right now We are having a trouble to make peer to peer call, For peer to peer call it requires to recognize both caller collie is in under same asterisk.
Any advice will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way for such setup - not use asterisk, use kamailio proxy

If you still want do it using asterisk - check dundi module, modify your dialplan to check on which server you peer NOW, before you call it.